# Javascript setTimeout does not work.

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Can someone explain why setTimeout() does not work properly here? Function timeLoop() runs only once. I read lots of answers to similar questions but none helped.

```
var Timer = function(){
    var startTime;
    var currentTime;
    var stop = false;
    var me = this;

    this.initTimer = function(){
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = '0';
    }

    this.startTimer = function(){
        this.start = new Date().getTime();
        this.stop = false;
        this.timeLoop();
    }

    this.stopTimer = function(){
        this.stop = true;
    }
    this.timeLoop = function(){
        if(this.stop) return;
        this.currentTime = new Date().getTime() - this.start;
        this.refreshTimer();
        setTimeout(function(){me.timeLoop();}, 10);
    }
    this.refreshTimer = function(){
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = this.currentTime.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually...it works for me, here it is in JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8RXca/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works for me. I suspect that you are not correctly creating a `new Timer()` or not calling its methods appropriately. The following works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='timer'>placeholder</div>
<button onclick="tim.startTimer();">Start</button>
<button onclick="tim.stopTimer();">Stop</button>
<script>
var Timer = function(){
    var startTime;
    var currentTime;
    var stop = false;
    var me = this;

    this.initTimer = function(){
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = '0';
    }

    this.startTimer = function(){
        this.start = new Date().getTime();
        this.stop = false;
        this.timeLoop();
    }

    this.stopTimer = function(){
        this.stop = true;
    }
    this.timeLoop = function(){
        if(this.stop) return;
        this.currentTime = new Date().getTime() - this.start;
        this.refreshTimer();
        setTimeout(function(){me.timeLoop();}, 10);
    }
    this.refreshTimer = function(){
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = this.currentTime.toString();
    }
}
var tim = new Timer();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You might need window.setInterval instead of setTimeout, read this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval

Comment: It does not answer the question, though. The question was (rephrased) "Why does the recursion here not work?", an answer of "Use a loop" _may_ be a solution but is not an actual answer to the question asked.

Comment: it does answer the question, window.setInterval is the answer, how to use is a different question.

Comment: @Bhavin The question is, and I repeat, "Why does the recursion not work?", not "How to make it work?". Yours is a solution, not an answer.

Comment: @Bhavin a `setTimeout()` which calls a function upon the timer expiring, which then makes a new call to setTimeout, _should_ work. This does not answer the question as to why it doesn't work in the OP supplied code, but rather suggests a different approach (setInterval) to solving a similar problem. If the OP wants to know _why_ the setTimeout approach is not working then suggesting a different approach does nothing to answer the question. Maybe the OP has already switched to setInterval and wants to know why the original approach didn't work.

Comment: @Bharvin What is so hard to understand - you are **not supposed** to be "spoon feeding" the solution here. The question is absolutely valid - as **Stephen P** said, this is code that should work, but OP observes that it doesn't. The question is "Why is the thing that should work, actually doing the opposite". Consider the following - if somebody encounters that, for whatever reason, 2+2 produces 5, and they'd want to know why, answering "Just do 1+3" does not explain it, correct?

Comment: @Bhavin So, therefore it follows that your solution is also not an answer, as you did the equivalent of "Just do 1+3" by not giving an explanation but a workaround. We are done here, I have no clue why until now you refused to acknowledge what was clearly explained to you multiple times.